# How to style this button in CSS to appear pushed down?

Tags: html, css, button

The button has these basic styles to make it look sort of 3D with a flat look.

```
background-color: #7a7acc;
border: none;
border-radius: 10px;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 0px #4747b2;
color: #fff;
font-family: Lato;
font-size: 16pt;
font-weight: bold;
height: 36px;
```

How can I make it appear pushed down like it appears now with the `box-shadow`, except above? I considered using -4px instead of 4px, but that doesn't move the button down 4 pixels. How can I do this properly? I also have to move the text down 4 pixels.

Comment: just an idea: `box-shadow: inset 0px 4px 0px #4747b2;`

Comment: Actually, this is much better. I could use a negative for the current state, positive for the pushed down state, and have the button be full size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to button to appear pushed down when its pushed down

add and active psuedo class and then `position relative` and then add a `top:#px` to it

```
.btn:active{
position:relative;
top:4px;
}
```

here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/p5w4x/

Comment: Thank you for the CSS selector, I didn't mean to make the button move down, I meant to make it seem inset. The comment on my question is what I'll use for that.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to center either button vertically, this should do the trick:

vertical-align: middle;

Comment: No, it's to style the button to look pushed in.